# Can't get form to work with unique variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where I want to be able to add select fields through another MySQL table.

The way my table is set up is like so:

OptionTitle
Option1
Option2
Option3

So for an example, here could be an example

```
OptionTitle: Race:
Option1: Male
Option2: Female
Option3: Unknown
```

However, there can be multiple custom select fields so here's where my problem comes from. Here's the code I have so far:

```
$query100 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mybb_option WHERE gid='" . $id . "'");

 while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query100))
 {
$query101 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mybb_option WHERE id = '$row2[id]'");
echo "
  <div class=\"divform\" id=\"$row2[optiontitle]\">
    <label for=\"$row2[optiontitle]\">$row2[optiontitle]:</label>
    <select name=\"$row2[optiontitle]\" id=\"$row2[optiontitle]\">";

     while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($query101))

 {
echo "<option value='$row6[option1]'>$row6[option1]</option>";
echo "<option value='$row6[option2]'>$row6[option2]</option>";
echo "<option value='$row6[option3]'>$row6[option3]</option>";
 }
    echo "
  </select>
  </div>
";          
 }
```

It might look fairly confusing and that's because of the name of the select field. I choose to use a variable as the ID because it would make sense for this variable to carry over so I can get more than one select field when I submit. If it wasn't a variable, then when I carry it over in the submit process it would only reveal one of the select fields.

I believe the submit process is where I'm the most lost.

```
$query100 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mybb_option WHERE gid='" . $id . "'");

 while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($query100)){

$row2[optiontitle] = $db->escape_string($_POST['$row2[optiontitle]']); //
     echo "$row2[optiontitle]";
$query30 = $db->query("INSERT `mybb_optiongame` SET `gid` = '".$id."', `mid` = 'MIDHERE', `optiontitle` = 'OPTION TITLE', `option1` = '$row2[optiontitle]'")or die(     mysqli_error());

 }
```

As you can see, I do a while for every select field I should have. I try to grab the variable by "$row2[optiontitle] = $db->escape_string($_POST['$row2[optiontitle]']);" but I don't think this was the right way to go about it. Can anyone help?

Comment: from where variable $row2 come from??